# Полноценный Drag N Drop, фигуры не прилипают к доске d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag, drop

Дан код. Взят у пользователя Stranger in the Q, и чуток подправлен.
[Halma Stranger in the Q](https://ru.files.fm/u/tn3t4j8f)
Помогите хотя бы сделать так чтобы фигуры прилипали при отпускании мыши к точке (120,120) (это касается только тронутой фигуры)...

```html
//ctrl+wheel увеличить масштаб
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Project 1.0.0.1</title>
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 <style>
html,body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
<script>
//src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"
//scr="d3.js"
var delta = 100;

var x7k = [200]
var y4k = [200]
var ii = 0
for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
    ii++;
    x7k[ii]=x*delta;
    y4k[ii]=y*delta;
}}
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 1024)
   .attr("width", 1366);
/*var img0=canvas.append("svg:image")
   
  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  .attr("x",677)
  .attr("y",0)
  var img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
*/
for (var ii=2;ii<=81;ii=ii+2){
  img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  .attr("x",x7k[ii])
  .attr("y",y4k[ii])
  }
/*var img2=canvas.append("svg:image")  
  img2=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "2.svg")
  .attr("x",x7k[8])
  .attr("y",y4k[0])
  */
  
var polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
    polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
    polygon0.attr("points", [0,0,111,122,222,222,212,122])// здесь было исправлено
    polygon0.style("fill", `rgba(100,11,11,0.5)`)
    polygon0.style("stroke", "black")
    polygon0.style("strokeWidth", "1px")  
    
var radius = 45;
var circle_data1 = d3.range(18).map(function(i) {
  return {x: 100+i*50, y: rnd()};
});
 
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circles")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circle_data1)
  //.data(circle_data2)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return (d.x)})
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return (d.y)})
  .attr("r", radius)
  .style('transition', "200ms")
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    if(i<=8){
 return `rgba(100,112,222,0.5)`
 
 }
 
 
 
 else {return `rgba(0,255,121,0.5)` }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  .call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .raise()
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('transition', "unset")
        }).on("drag", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
            .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
        }).on("end", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
            .style('transition', "200ms")
        })
  );
/*ball.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  };*/
function upd () {

  var newData = [
    50, 50,   150, 50,   250, 50,
    50, 150, 150, 150,   250, 150,
    50, 250, 150, 250,   250, 250,
    (6-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,
    (6-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,
    (6-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50
    
      ///*//////
    
  ]

  circle_data1.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.x = newData[i * 2]
    d.y = newData[i * 2 + 1]
 
  })

  circles.data(circle_data1)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return (d.x)})
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return (d.y)})
}
upd();
function rnd() {
  return 20 + Math.random() * 110
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот реализация кода уголки (осталось только AI реализовать). Здесь применен Drag N Drop метод с библиотекой d3.js и работа @Stranger in the Q с кружочками + мое умение прибавлять к коду привычки...

1. Исправлена ошибка с клеткой 1*1 (Фигура теперь правильно виснит).
2. Исправлена ошибка прилипания по координате {y}: теперь все четко работает.
3. Добавлено подобие аннотации (краткое).
4. Код ниже новее (лучше), чем код в архиве (ссылка выше), но в папку с проектом нужно поместить нарисованный черный квадрат с именем 1.svg размером 75*75 пикселей, чтобы нарисовалась доска, но если вы качаете файл по ссылке выше, то все уже включено.

```html
//src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"
//scr="d3.js"

<textarea rows="2" cols="17" id="T0"></textarea>
<textarea rows="2" cols="17" id="T1"></textarea>
<input width = "200" height="100" rows="111" cols="111" type="button" value="save" onclick="saving0()"> </input>
<button onclick="upd()">New Game!!!()</button><br>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Project 1.0.0.1</title>
<style type="text/css">
textarea {
   font-size: 20pt;
   font-family: Arial;
} 
</style>
<style>

</style>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 
 
 <style>
 


 </style>

 
<body>
<script>
//So I Set Scale
var scale = 'scale(0.8)';
document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scale;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
document.body.style.msTransform =   scale;       // IE 9
document.body.style.transform = scale;     // General
//document.body.style.zoom = 0.6;
// 

//Set to Off scrolling\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
/*<style>
html,body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
 </style>
*/
//So I import libs
//src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"
//scr="d3.js"
//document.body.style.zoom = 1.0 //Scale P1
//Set to Off scrolling/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var delta = 100;
var delimiter1 = '_';
var delimiter2 = '.'
var delimiter3 = ',';



//I'm Create 180*64 2d array P2 <

var G = [];
var M = [];
//var S = [];




//I am creating N-dimensional Array via make function
/*function make(dim, lvl, arr) {
  if (lvl === 1) return [];
  if (!lvl) lvl = dim;
  if (!arr) arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = dim; i < l; i += 1) {
arr[i] = make(dim, lvl - 1, arr[i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
*/



for(var i=0; i<=8; i++){
  G[i] = [];
  M[i] = [];
  
}
//I'm Create 1000*200*64*64 4d array P2



//M[1][1]=10;
//alert(M[1][1]);
for(var x=1;x<9;x++){
for(var y=1;y<9;y++){
M[y][x] = 0;
G[y][x] = 0;



 
}

}
//M[][] = = = = = == = = = = == = = ==  = == =  = == == = = == == = = = ===  = == = = = = = = = = = == = = = = = = =  ==  == ==== == = == = = = == = = = = == =  == = = == == = = ==   == =  === = = = ==  = == = = = = ==  == = ============
M[1][1] = 1;
M[2][1] = 2 ;
M[3][1] = 3;
M[1][2] = 4;
M[2][2] = 5;
M[3][2] = 6;
M[1][3] = 7;
M[2][3] = 8;
M[3][3] = 9; 
M[6][6] = 10;
M[7][6] = 11;
M[8][6] = 12;
M[6][7] = 13;
M[7][7] = 14;
M[8][7] = 15;
M[6][8] = 16;
M[7][8] = 17;
M[8][8] = 18; 
ii=0;
 
  for(var y=1; y<9;y++){
      for(var x=1; x<9;x++){
ii++;
    if(M[x][y]!=0){
    //console.log(M[x][y]);
    
    } 
    
  }}

var ii = 0;
var YY = 0;
var XX = 0;

   for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
ii++;
    XX=x*delta+delta/2;
    YY=y*delta+delta/2;
G[x][y]=XX+delimiter1+YY;
   // console.log("ii: ", ii, "x: " , x, "y: " , y, G[x][y])



}}

var delta = 100;
var delimiter1 = '_';


//I'm Create 8*8 2d array P2
var G = [];
for(var i=0; i<=8; i++){
  G[i] = [];
  
}/*
//I'm creating N-dimensional array;
function createNDimArray(dims) {
return dims.length === 1
    ? new Array(dims[0])
    : Array.apply(null, Array(dims[0])).map(createNDimensionalArray.bind(null, dims.slice(1)));
}
createNDimArray([3, 2, 5]); // returns 3x2x5 array
*/
//let CurentXY = [2+1]
//let Last_XY = [2+1]
//Help10=1;//
//helloWorld

var ii = 0;
var YY = 0;
var XX = 0;

   for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
ii++;
    XX=x*delta+delta/2;
    YY=y*delta+delta/2;
G[x][y]=XX+delimiter1+YY;
//console.log("ii: ", ii, "x: " , x, "y: " , y, G[x][y])



}}



//let Love_Gravity = []
var x7k = [200];
var y4k = [200];
ii=0;
for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
ii++;
x7k[ii]=x*delta;
y4k[ii]=y*delta;
}}
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 1024)
   .attr("width", 1366)
   
   
   
//canvas.strokeRect(5, 5, 25, 15)
/*entry = prompt("Enter your name")
entryArray = entry.split("");
*/

/*var img0=canvas.append("svg:image")

  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  .attr("x",677)
  .attr("y",0)
  var img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
*/
var width0 = screen.width;
var height0 = screen.height;
var delta2=400;
let delta3=100;
for (var ii=2;ii<=81;ii=ii+2){
  img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  //.attr("x",x7k[ii] +delta2)
  //.attr("y",y4k[ii] +delta3)
  .attr("x",x7k[ii])
  .attr("y",y4k[ii])
  }
/*var img2=canvas.append("svg:image")
  img2=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "2.svg")
  .attr("x",x7k[8])
  .attr("y",y4k[0])
  */
//So I draw Polygon with specific color
var polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
polygon0.attr("points", [0,0,100,0,100,100,0,100])// здесь было исправлено
polygon0.style("fill", `rgba(100,111,111,0.5)`)
polygon0.style("stroke", "black")
polygon0.style("strokeWidth", "1px")
var t_4 = canvas.append("text")
  .style("fill", "black")
  .style("font-size", "31px")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(260,330) rotate(100)")
  .text("MyTextContent")
  
function AAA(){
console.log("I Love you_:" , "God");
}
var run = setInterval(AAA,111)  //Warning!!! function must be called AAA instead AAA();

var radius = 45;
var X1=0;var Y1=0;
var circle_data1 = d3.range(18).map(function(i) {
  return {x: 100+i*50, y: rnd_1()};
});

ii=0;
 let XL=0; var YL=0; var XY; var ZZ=[2];
 function G_To_Y(x1,y1){
 for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   
       ii++;
       XY=null;
       XY=(G[x][y]).split(delimiter1);
       if(XY[0]<=x1+delta/2 && XY[0]>=x1-delta/2 && XY[1]<=y1+delta/2 && XY[1]>=y1-delta/2){
   ZZ[0]=x+1;  ZZ[1]=y+1;
       XL=XY[0];  YL=XY[1];
      // console.log(x , "__1111 ", y, " 1111_ ", XY[1], "");
   return YL;
       }  
  

}}

 
 }
 function G_To_X(x1,y1){
 for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   
       ii++;
       XY=null;
       XY=(G[x][y]).split(delimiter1);
       if(XY[0]<=x1+delta/2 && XY[0]>=x1-delta/2 && XY[1]<=y1+delta/2 && XY[1]>=y1-delta/2){
   ZZ[0]=x+1;  ZZ[1]=y+1;
       XL=XY[0];  YL=XY[1];
      // console.log(x , "__1111 ", y, " 1111_ ", XY[1], "");
   return XL;
       }  
   

}}

 
 }
 
 function G_To_Y____2(x1,y1){
 for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   
       ii++;
       XY=null;
       XY=(G[x][y]).split(delimiter1);
       if(XY[0]<=x1+delta/2 && XY[0]>=x1-delta/2 && XY[1]<=y1+delta/2 && XY[1]>=y1-delta/2){
   ZZ[0]=x+1;  ZZ[1]=y+1;
       XL=XY[0];  YL=XY[1];
      // console.log(x , "__1111 ", y, " 1111_ ", XY[1], "");
   return YL;
       }  
  

}}

 
 }
 
 function G_To_X____2(x1,y1){
 for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   
       ii++;
       XY=null;
       XY=(G[x][y]).split(delimiter1);
       if(XY[0]<=x1+delta/2 && XY[0]>=x1-delta/2 && XY[1]<=y1+delta/2 && XY[1]>=y1-delta/2){
   ZZ[0]=x+1;  ZZ[1]=y+1;
       XL=XY[0];  YL=XY[1];
      // console.log(x , "__1111 ", y, " 1111_ ", XY[1], "");
   return XL;
       }  
   

}}

 
 }
 
 
 
   
let A1=0;
let A2=0;

let B1=0;
let B2=0;

 var MoveNumbre=0;
 var Comanda=1;
 
 function GetComandNumber(){
 if(Comanda==1){Comanda=2;}
 else{Comanda=1;}
 }
 
 function ComboFinder(){
 if(Comanda==1){Comanda=2;}
 else{Comanda=1;}
 }
 
 
 
 
 var LZZ = [2];
 var FZZ = [2];
 var LGG = [2];
 var FGG = [2];
 LZZ[0]=0;
 LZZ[1]=0;
 FZZ[0]=0;
 FZZ[1]=0;
 
 LGG[0]=0;
 LGG[1]=0;
 FGG[0]=0;
 FGG[1]=0;
 
 
 /*
 A1=ZZ[1];
 A2=ZZ[0];
function CorrectedMove(){
 for(var x=1; x<=8;x++){
  for(var y=1; y<=8;y++){
      
if(M[${ZZ[1]}][${ZZ[0]}]!=0) && M[${ZZ[1]}][${ZZ[0]}]>9) {console.log("general movement");}
}}
console.log("FF","general movement");
}*/


  
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circles")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circle_data1)
  //.data(circle_data2)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return (d.x)})
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return (d.y)})
  .attr("r", radius)
  .style('transition', "200ms")
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
if(i<=8){
    return `rgba(100,112,222,0.5)`
 
    }



    else {return `rgba(0,255,121,0.5)` }
  })






  .call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d,i) {
      
          X1=d.x;
      Y1=d.y;
       
          
          X1=G_To_X(X1,Y1);
      Y1=G_To_Y(X1,Y1);
          
        
          
          FGG[1] = G_To_Y(X1,Y1);
          FGG[0] = G_To_X(X1,Y1);
          FZZ[1] = ZZ[1];
          FZZ[0] = ZZ[0];
    
         // setText0("From: " + G_To_X(X1,Y1)+"_"+ G_To_Y(X1,Y1)+ "_" + ZZ[1] +"_"+ ZZ[0]);
          setText0("From: " + FGG[1]+"_"+ FGG[0]+ "_" + FZZ[1] +"_"+ FZZ[0]  + "_" + M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]);
          //console.log("From_",  ZZ[1],"_", ZZ[0]);
          d3.select(this)
        
            
            
            .raise()
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style('transition', "unset")
    }).on("drag", function(d) {
      d3.select(this)
          
        .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
        .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y)
            .attr('stroke', 'red')
       // d3.event.x)
            //d3.event.y)
    }).on("end", function(d,i) {
        X1=d.x
        Y1=d.y
            
             
          
          
          LGG[1] = G_To_Y(X1,Y1);
          LGG[0] = G_To_X(X1,Y1);
          LZZ[1] = ZZ[1];
          LZZ[0] = ZZ[0];
          if(M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]<10 ){ 
          //M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]=M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=0;
          
          alert("Замечание не трогайте не свои фигуры");
          d3.select(this)
            //.attr("cx", X1=d.x)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
       // .attr("cy", Y1=d.y)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr("cx", d.x = FGG[0])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
        .attr("cy", d.y =  FGG[1])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
        .style('transition', "200ms")
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            setText1("Last (To): " + LGG[1]+"_"+ LGG[0]+ "_" + LZZ[1] +"_"+ LZZ[0] + "_" + M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]); 
            setText0("From: " + FGG[1]+"_"+ FGG[0]+ "_" + FZZ[1] +"_"+ FZZ[0]  + "_" + M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]);
             }
          else if(M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]==0){
          Comanda=1;
          M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]=M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]];
          M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=0;
          
          MoveNumbre++;
          console.log("MoveNumbre: "+MoveNumbre+";"+" Comanda:"+ Comanda);
          //alert("Верный ход");
          DoMove(1,50,50,350,450);
          //if //DoMove( MoveNumber, 2,350,400);
          
          d3.select(this)
            //.attr("cx", X1=d.x)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
       // .attr("cy", Y1=d.y)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr("cx", d.x = G_To_X(X1,Y1))//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
        .attr("cy", d.y =  G_To_Y(X1,Y1))//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
        .style('transition', "200ms")
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            setText1("Last (To): " + LGG[1]+"_"+ LGG[0]+ "_" + LZZ[1] +"_"+ LZZ[0] + "_" + M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]); 
            setText0("From: " + FGG[1]+"_"+ FGG[0]+ "_" + FZZ[1] +"_"+ FZZ[0]  + "_" + M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]);
             }
             
         else if(M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]==M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]){ 
          alert("Ход не выполнен, т.к. задета одна и та же клетка");
          //M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]=M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=0;
          
          
          d3.select(this)
            //.attr("cx", X1=d.x)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
       // .attr("cy", Y1=d.y)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr("cx", d.x = FGG[0])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
        .attr("cy", d.y =  FGG[1])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
        .style('transition', "200ms")
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            setText1("Last (To): " + LGG[1]+"_"+ LGG[0]+ "_" + LZZ[1] +"_"+ LZZ[0] + "_" + M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]); 
            setText0("From: " + FGG[1]+"_"+ FGG[0]+ "_" + FZZ[1] +"_"+ FZZ[0]  + "_" + M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]);
             }
             
        else if(M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]>0 && M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]<19 ){ 
          
          alert("Неверный ход сдвоенная фигура");
          
          //M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]=M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]];
          //M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]=0;
          
          
          d3.select(this)
            //.attr("cx", X1=d.x)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
       // .attr("cy", Y1=d.y)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr("cx", d.x = FGG[0])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
        .attr("cy", d.y =  FGG[1])//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
        .style('transition', "200ms")
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            setText1("Last (To): " + LGG[1]+"_"+ LGG[0]+ "_" + LZZ[1] +"_"+ LZZ[0] + "_" + M[LZZ[1]][LZZ[0]]); 
            setText0("From: " + FGG[1]+"_"+ FGG[0]+ "_" + FZZ[1] +"_"+ FZZ[0]  + "_" + M[FZZ[1]][FZZ[0]]);
             }
              
             
             
    })
  );
/*ball.onmouseup = function() {
document.onmousemove = null;
ball.onmouseup = null;
  };*/
  

 
  
  
function upd () {

  var newData = [
50, 50,   150, 50,   250, 50,
50, 150, 150, 150,   250, 150,
50, 250, 150, 250,   250, 250,
(6-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,
(6-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,
(6-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50
   //  ()
  ///*//////

  ]

  circle_data1.forEach(function(d, i) {
d.x = newData[i * 2]
d.y = newData[i * 2 + 1]
  
  })


  circles.data(circle_data1)
.attr("cx", function(d) {return (d.x)})
.attr('stroke', 'black')
.attr("cy", function(d) {return (d.y)})
}


upd();




function rnd_1() {
  return (50 + Math.random() * 750)
}
function rnd_2(min, max, inc) {
min = min || 0;
inc = inc || 1;
if(!max) { return new Error('need to define a max');}

return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) / inc) * inc + min;
}


var U = localStorage["Key2"];
function saving0() {
  localStorage["Key2"] = (getText0());
}
function getText0() {
  str1 = document.getElementById('T0');
  return (str1.value + "");
}
function setText0(value) {
  document.getElementById('T0').value = value;
}
function setText1(value) {
  document.getElementById('T1').value = value;
}
setText0(U);
//setText1()

//And now I set scroll padding
/*window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: "smooth" });*/
//A_1:
//Saveka1
window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: 200, behavior: "smooth" });
//window.scrollTo({ left: 0, top: +400, behavior: "smooth" });
/*function Do(k){

circle_data1.forEach(function(d, i) {


if(k==i){

if(i==0){ 
d.y = 350+50;
    d.x = 350+150;
    
            }
else if(i==1){

    d.y = 400+50;
    d.x = 500+50;
    

}
else if(i==2){

 
    d.y = 400+50;
    d.x = 600+50;
    
//d.x = 450    
}
}}}

*/

function DoMove ( FF, ZY_0, ZX_0,   ZY_2,ZX_2) { //Найти 

 /*Memories0 add to Function  MoveNumbre   DoMove( FF,FZ,FZ,LZ,LZ) */
 /*M1:Translate Z to GG */
 //M2: Over Boundes 8 * 8 y x alert() 
   circle_data1.forEach(function(d, i) {
 //InSaving :
   FF=rnd_2(1,8,1);
   if(i==FF){
  //setTimeout(function(){console.log("XX")}, 500);
d.x = rnd_2(0,7,1)*100+50; 
d.y = rnd_2(0,7,1)*100+50; 
    //console.log(FGG[0]+ "_" + FGG[1]+ "_"+ LGG[1]+"_"+LGG[0])
    Comanda=2;
  }
  })


  circles.data(circle_data1)
.attr("cx", function(d) {return (d.x)})
.attr('stroke', 'black')
.attr("cy", function(d) {return (d.y)})
}
//So It's how canI split
//let U=getText0();
//let entryArray
//let entry = "Hello World";
//entryArray = entry.split(" ");


//console.log(entryArray[0],"_")

function createNDimArray(dimensions) {
if (dimensions.length > 0) {
    var dim = dimensions[0];
    var rest = dimensions.slice(1);
    var newArray = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        newArray[i] = createNDimArray(rest);
    }
    return newArray;
 } else {
    return undefined;
 }
 }
//var S0=createNDimArray([3, 5, 5, 5]);//returns a 3x2x5x5 array.


//I'm creating 4d array
//var  S = make(6,11);
S0[5][5][5][5]="22222222";
//alert(S0[5][5][5][5]);
//Beging of basic configuration of figures 
//function S0 {}









</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Получилось. Добавил залипание к точке (120, 120) Теперь осталось сделать функцию проверки и возвращения координаты. А так, все - работает. Как будет готово, напишу сюда.

```html
//ctrl+wheel увеличить масштаб
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Project 1.0.0.1</title>
<html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
 <style>
html,body{
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
</style>
<body>
<script>
//src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"
//scr="d3.js"
var delta = 100;

var x7k = [200]
var y4k = [200]
var ii = 0
for(var y=0; y<=8;y++){
   for(var x=0; x<=8;x++){
    ii++;
    x7k[ii]=x*delta;
    y4k[ii]=y*delta;
}}
var canvas = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("height", 1024)
   .attr("width", 1366);
/*var img0=canvas.append("svg:image")
   
  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  .attr("x",677)
  .attr("y",0)
  var img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
*/
for (var ii=2;ii<=81;ii=ii+2){
  img1=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "1.svg")
  .attr("x",x7k[ii])
  .attr("y",y4k[ii])
  }
/*var img2=canvas.append("svg:image")  
  img2=canvas.append("svg:image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "2.svg")
  .attr("x",x7k[8])
  .attr("y",y4k[0])
  */
  
var polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
    polygon0=canvas.append("polygon")
    polygon0.attr("points", [0,0,111,122,222,222,212,122])// здесь было исправлено
    polygon0.style("fill", `rgba(100,11,11,0.5)`)
    polygon0.style("stroke", "black")
    polygon0.style("strokeWidth", "1px")  
    
var radius = 45;
var circle_data1 = d3.range(18).map(function(i) {
  return {x: 100+i*50, y: rnd()};
});
 
var circles = d3.select("svg")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "circles")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circle_data1)
  //.data(circle_data2)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return (d.x)})
  .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return (d.y)})
  .attr("r", radius)
  .style('transition', "200ms")
  .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
    if(i<=8){
 return `rgba(100,112,222,0.5)`
 
 }
 
 
 
 else {return `rgba(0,255,121,0.5)` }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  
  .call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .raise()
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('transition', "unset")
        }).on("drag", function(d) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x)
            .attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y)
   .attr('stroke', 'red')
   
        }).on("end", function(d,i) {
          d3.select(this)
            .attr("cx", d.x = 120)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
            .attr("cy", d.y = 120)//здесь добавил код залипания к тоске (120; 120);
   .attr('stroke', 'transparent')
            .style('transition', "200ms")
   .attr('stroke', 'black')
        })
  );
/*ball.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ball.onmouseup = null;
  };*/
function upd () {

  var newData = [
    50, 50,   150, 50,   250, 50,
    50, 150, 150, 150,   250, 150,
    50, 250, 150, 250,   250, 250,
    (6-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (6-1)*100+50,
    (6-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (7-1)*100+50,
    (6-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,   (7-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50,    (8-1)*100+50, (8-1)*100+50
    
      ///*//////
    
  ]

  circle_data1.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.x = newData[i * 2]
    d.y = newData[i * 2 + 1]
 
  })

  circles.data(circle_data1)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {return (d.x)})
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return (d.y)})
}
upd();
function rnd() {
  return 20 + Math.random() * 110
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а что это такое ? не игра - не что то такое - а что это ?

Comment: @ MaximLensky, не понял в чем прикол, это игра уголки, я ее пока не доделал.